# How to generate recommendation with matrix factorization

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, latent-semantic-analysis

I've read some papers of Matrix Factorization(Latent Factor Model) in Recommendation System,and I can implement the algorithm.I can get the similar RMSE result like the paper said on the MovieLens dataset.

However I find out that,if I try to generate a top-K(e.g K=10) recommended movies list for every user by rank the predicted rating,it seems that the movies that are thought to be rated high point of all users are the same.

Is that just what it works or I've got something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in recommendation.

It is sometimes called "Harry Potter" effect - (almost) everybody likes Harry Potter.
So most automated procedures will find out which items are generally popular, and recommend those to the users.

You can either filter out very popular items, or multiply the predicted rating by a factor that is lower the more globally popular an item is.